# The equation with binomial coefficient

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, roots, integers

> Find all positive integars $n,k$ such that
> $$\binom{n-1}{k+1}=\binom{n+1}{k-1}$$

#### My work so far:

$n-1\ge k+1 \Rightarrow n \ge k+2$
$$\binom{n-1}{k+1}=\binom{n+1}{k-1}$$
$$\frac{(n-1)!}{(k+1)!(n-k-2)!}=\frac{(n+1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k+2)!}$$
$$\frac{1}{k(k+1)}=\frac{n(n+1)}{(n-k-1)(n-k)(n-k+1)(n-k+2)}$$
$$(n-k-1)(n-k)(n-k+1)(n-k+2)=k(k+1)n(n+1)$$
I used [http://www.wolframalpha.com/](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(n-k-1)(n-k)(n-k%2B1)(n-k%2B2)%3Dk(k%2B1)n(n%2B1))
$$k=1, n=3$$

> #### Q: *How to solve this problem without computer (wolframalpha.com)?*

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: How to solve this problem without computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** The left hand-side term is the product of 4 consecutive non negative integers and should be equal two products of 2 consecutive integers.

You are in the situation where $a(a+1)(a+2)(a+3)=b(b+1)c(c+1)$, with $1 \leq b < b+1 \leq c < c+1$. You can prove (mostly by contradiction) that $b=a$ and $c=a+2$.