# The equation with binomial coefficient $\binom{n-m}{k+m}=\binom{n+m}{k-m}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, integers

> Find all positive integers $n,k$ such that
>   $$\binom{n-m}{k+m}=\binom{n+m}{k-m}$$

1) I solved problem if $m=1$. Its here: [$k=1; n=3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2355015/the-equation-with-binomial-coefficient)

2) $$\binom{n-m}{k+m}=\binom{n+m}{k-m}$$
$k=m, n=3m$ is root of this equation.

*Does this equation have other roots?*

Comment: Numerical search for binomial coefficients up to $10000000$ only found the non-integral solution $n=\frac{29}{2},\, k=\frac{11}{2},\,m=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Are you asking _for a fixed $m$_ what are the solutions?

Comment: @alex.jordan: Yes exactly. $m$ is fixed.

Comment: Are you interested only in n,m,k integers or also in n,m,k reals? you tagged it with integer so I would assume just integers right?

Comment: $n,k,m -$ positive integers

Comment: $k=m,n=3m$  leads to the result ${2m \choose 2m}={4m \choose 0}$ which is certainly true though not very exciting

Comment: Equivalent is: $\,\binom {4m+j}{2m} \binom {2m+j}{2m} = \binom {4m+j+i}{2m} \binom {2m+i}{2m}\,$ with $\,i,j\in\mathbb{N}_0\,$ and $\,i\leq j$

Comment: The non-integer solution found by @PeterTaylor is part of a larger family described by: $m=\frac{1}{2}$, $k=F_{2i}F_{2i+3}+\frac{1}{2}$, $n=F_{2i}F_{2i+5}+\frac{3}{2}$, where $F_i$ denotes $i$-th Fibonacci number.

Comment: There's a weird relationship between this problem and Fibonacci numbers. For fixed $n$; the maximum of $\binom{n-k}{k}$ is attained approximately at $k=\frac{n}{\varphi^2}$. Furthermore, one can recall the identity $\sum_{k\geq0}\binom{n-k}{k}=F_n$. And of course, there's the solution family @PeterKošinár found. This all seems extremely suspicious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't figure out how to get the roots, but I have tried for an approximation.
Starting with $$\binom{n-m}{k+m} = \binom{n+m}{k-m}$$
This is
$$\frac{(n-m)!}{(k+m)!(n-k-2m)!} = \frac{(n+m)!}{(k-m)!(n-k+2m)!} =$$
$$\frac{(n-m)(n-m-1)...(n-k-2m+1)}{(k+m)!} = \frac{(n+m)(n+m-1)...(n-k+2m+1)}{(k-m)!}$$
Note that the first numerator has $k+m$ products while the second has $k-m$ products.
$$Numerator_1(k-m)! = Numerator_2(k+m)!$$
$$Numerator_1 = Numerator_2(k+m)(k+m-1)...(k-m+1)$$
There are $2m$ products in the expression following numerator 2.
Thus, for $k$ and $n$ large, $m$ and $k$ approximately satisfy 
$$k + m = 2m(k-m)$$

Comment: I understand your answer all of it except this part $\frac{(n-m)(n-m-1)...(n-k-2m+1)}{(k+m)!} = \frac{(n+m)(n+m-1)...(n-k+2m+1)}{(k-m)!}$, could you please explain to me what you did in this step ?

Comment: Since $(n-m)! > (n-k-2m)!$, I eliminated $(n-k-2m)!$ from the denominator. The last product before $(n-k-2m)$ is $(n-k-2m+1)$, then you have $(n-k-2m)!/(n-k-2m)!$. Similar approach for the second fraction.

Comment: Thanks for explanation.