# The equation with binomial coefficient $\binom{t}{l}=\binom{t+m}{l-m}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, integers

> Find all positive integers $l,t$ such that
>   $$\binom{t}{l}=\binom{t+m}{l-m}$$

#### My work so far:

1) I solved problem if $m=2$. Its here: [where $l=k+1; t=n-1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2355015/the-equation-with-binomial-coefficient)

2) If $m=1$ then 
$$\binom{t}{l}=\binom{t+1}{l-1}$$

$$l=m, t=m$$ and $$l=F_{2i}F_{2i+3}+1, t=F_{2i}F_{2i+5}+1$$ is roots of this equation, where $i \ge 0$ and $F_i -$  [Fibonacci number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number)

> Q.: 1) Does this equation have other roots in case $m=1$?
>
> 2) I need help for case $m\ge 3$